# 過去の同一日を取得する際に月末を考慮に入れる方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

特定の日付から過去10年分の同一日を取得したいのですが、
指定する日付が月末であった場合は月末に変更したいです。

このように書いたのですが、もう少し良い書き方はありますか？

```
  def same_dates_in_past(date)
    #date = Date.new(2017,2,28)
    end_of_month = date == date.end_of_month
    dates = 10.times.map{|i| date - i.years}
    dates.map!(&:end_of_month) if end_of_month
    dates
  end
```

もう少し短く簡潔に書けるかと思ったのですが、うまく書けませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問のコードで十分短かいですし、分かり易い物を使うのが一番だと思いますが、`send`メソッドを使用して、呼ぶメソッドを動的に決定する例です。

```
def same_dates_in_past(date)
    m = (date == date.end_of_month) ? :end_of_month : :itself
    10.times.map{|i| (date - i.years).send(m)}
end
```

月末日の場合「1日足して、1年引いて、1日引く」例。
rails非依存。月末日に1日足すとn月1日になり、n月1日から1日引くと月末日になる事を利用。

```
def same_dates_in_past(date)
    p = (date + 1).day == 1 ? 1 : 0
    10.times.map{|i| (date + p).prev_year(i) - p}
end
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。後から読んだ時に意図がわかりやすいように元のコードを使うことにします。